# Oracle Trigger creates with compilation error but actually there is no error

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

So I created the following trigger, when I am creating the issue its not coming out to the command promt and keeps blinking on the the next line.

```
drop trigger insert_data_to_employee;
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER insert_data_to_employee
AFTER INSERT ON dummy_emp
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
-- Insert record into employee table
INSERT INTO employee
   ( lname,
     ssn,
     salary,
     dno)
   VALUES
   ( 'smith',
     '123456785',
     98765,
     1);
END;/
```

please help !! any help is much appreciated

Comment: run , "show errors"  Use an IDE to edit/compile pl/sql code - such SQLDeveloper, which is free to download.

Comment: What UI are you using?

Comment: Depending on the UI you're using you may need to get rid of the `/` after `END;`.

Comment: if it is SQLPlus, it might be that the "/" (end of block UI declaration) is expected in a new line. the behavior you're describing sounds like the UI didn't understand you finish writing the command, and expects additional characters.

Answer (score 1):

I just validated my suspicious.

In SQLPlus if you'll input the command like that - the UI will not "understand" that you finished the command, and will expect more characters before parsing the text you submitted.

you have to put the ending mark "/" on a new line.

run:

```
drop trigger insert_data_to_employee;
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER insert_data_to_employee
AFTER INSERT ON dummy_emp
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
-- Insert record into employee table
INSERT INTO employee
   ( lname,
     ssn,
     salary,
     dno)
   VALUES
   ( 'smith',
     '123456785',
     98765,
     1);
END;
/
```

And it will compile.

Please not that this is an SQLPlus thing, not a "syntax" issue.
that's the way this UI handles multiple lines submitted in a command prompt app.